# Loading QGIS Python tools in ArcMap?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, pyqgis

How to load QGIS Python tools in ArcMap?

For example, if I want to use any GDAL or GRASS tools in ArcMap.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you *can't* load QGIS Python tools into ArcMap. Arcpy and pyqgis are different coding languages.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If it's a Python-based tool, you can add the location of the tool to your Python environment and import it in the ArcGIS Python Interpreter window.

If there's a command-line version available, you can also call it from the Python interpreter, just use Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to do so.

I don't think there is a way to get just any tool from QGIS into ArcMap with its GUI, etc.